# `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` when trying to set a list of files as an array variable in bash

Tags: bash

Maybe I'm being really silly here but I can't seem to figure this out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
DELTAS=($(ls -p /foo/bar/ | grep -P '^\d+[^\.]+\.sh$'))
...
```

If I run this interactively it's fine, and `echo $DELTAS` returns:

```
1-foo.sh
2-bar.sh
```

However, when this is run inside a bash script, I receive `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`; any ideas?

Comment: Please update your question to show us the entire script, including the `#!` line. Copy and paste it, don't re-type it. The error message implies that your script is being run using `sh` rather than `bash`. In a comment you say the script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (`#!/bin/bash` would be simpler). Are you certain you have the syntax of the `#!` line right?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Execute that script file as bash <file name>.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you've not put `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script, and so it's running using `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash`.  This would run under dash rather than bash on Ubuntu, for example.

That syntax is a bash extension.

Comment: My scripts start with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, but still nope :(

Comment: If you execute it with `sh myscript.sh`, though, the shebang is ignored.

Comment: Try `bash ./scriptname.sh` ?

Comment: Winner! I knew it was something silly!